# is there a javascript counterpart to php's native hash() function?

Tags: javascript

I am converting a php script to java script and all is well except I can't find a simple js function that takes a string and outputs a SHA-512 hash hex string like php's hash() function.

This is a really corny thing that takes user's typed in text and uses the hash to generate "random art" so I am not really concerned with the security aspects of the hash function

I found:

```
 crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-512', stringvar);
```

but that doesn't produce the nice hex string I expected.  I found a further loop to convert the digest to a hex string but it's ugly and I was hoping there was just a simple function I am missing.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no hashing built in to javascript natively (that I know of). There are js Libs that can be found very easily, though using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no native solution but a simple Google research point to cryptoJS or this [link](https://coursesweb.net/javascript/sha512-encrypt-hash_cs)

Answer (score 0):

This is the [Javascript implementation of Java’s String.hashCode() method](https://werxltd.com/wp/2010/05/13/javascript-implementation-of-javas-string-hashcode-method/)

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function() {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (this.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
 return hash;
};
```

But if that doesn't help you, you have [this library](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha512) that hashes with SHA-512, SHA-384, SHA-512/224, SHA-512/256 in JS